# Firebase Push in Textview

Tags: android, textview

i have a question .. How can i save push Notification in a textView to my second activity .. this my codes. Thank you for the help...

```
public class FCM_service extends FirebaseMessagingService {
public static String dato;
String type="";

TextView texto ;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    if(remoteMessage.getData().size() >0){
        type="json";
        sendNotificatio(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
    }
    if(remoteMessage.getNotification() !=null) {
        type = "message";
        sendNotificatio(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
}
public void sendNotificatio(String messageBody) {
    String id="";
    String message="";
    String titles="";

    if (type.equals("json")){
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(messageBody);
            id=jsonObject.getString("id");
            message=jsonObject.getString("message");
            titles= jsonObject.getString("title");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else if (type.equals("message")) {
        message= messageBody;
    }
    Intent i = new Intent(FCM_service.this,MainActivity.class);

    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(titles)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0,builder.build());
    Log.d("LOGTA", "NOTIFICACION RECIBIDA");
    Log.d("LOGTAG", "Título:" + titles);
    Log.d("LOGTAG", "Texto: " + message);
    String dato = message;
    i.putExtra("MENSAJE", dato);
    Log.e("Mensajito", dato);

}
}
```

i tried to use intent/bundle to send the message to an other activity...but i always received null and Exception Error.. someone help please

Comment: what you want to save exatly, the data, the message?

Comment: yeah Bruno . i received the server message ..., but iwhat i want to do,is  catch this server message in a textView to my second  activity

Answer (score 1):

Just try this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(FCM_service.this,MainActivity.class);
i.putExtra("id",id);
i.putExtra("message",message);
i.putExtra("titles",titles);

i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

And in other activity:

```
String id=getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
String message=getIntent().getStringExtra("message");
String titles=getIntent().getStringExtra("titles");
```

To set **text**:

```
textview.setText(message);
```

Comment: THANK YOU A LOT BRUNO YOU SAVE MY DAY #RESPECT

Comment: No problem just accept answer and if you want and vote :) @WidMaer

Comment: Vote? how can i do that ?

Comment: just click in up arrow in the answer. above the 0.

Comment: if u dont ,ind a have an othe question ...  how can i advise  the user he have a notification .. on the icon app in the ui ... when the app is close(Like the socials red..whatsapp or facebook)...HOPE U NDERSTND MY QUESTION :)

Comment: This is a more complex answer but to do that just try creating an method inside the activity that ui changes, and do ui changes inside the method and call the method inside the `sendNotificatio()` in class **FCM_service**

Comment: I dont know the code of activity that you want to change when notification recived, because of that I can't help you better.